# ng-repeat nested json array angularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm trying to iterate comments inside a nested json object with angular ng-repeat directive, but in somehow it seems not accessing to it, what i am doing wrong?

**Here the json**

```
        posts: [
        {
            title: 'Free pizza at club meetings',
            upvotes: 15,
            comments: [
                {commento:'comment1'},
                {commento:'comment2'}
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'End all club emails with Laffy Taffy jokes',
            upvotes: 9,
            comments: [],
        }
];
```

**and here the view**

```
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 comment" ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    <p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="upVote(post)" style="cursor:pointer;"></span> Upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    </p>
    <p ng-repeat comment in post.comments>
    {{comment.commento}}
    </p>
</div>
```

the  in the view give me error

Comment: `ng-repeat="comment in post.comments"`

Comment: Sorry @Azola I didn't see your comment before posting my answer. If you post an answer I'll delete mine so you get the rep.

Comment: Nothing to worry about @BernhardHofmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just small syntax error- check the below code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29998/)

```js
var app = angular.module("demoApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.posts= [
            {
                title: 'Free pizza at club meetings',
                upvotes: 15,
                comments: [
                    {commento:'comment1'},
                    {commento:'comment2'}
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'End all club emails with Laffy Taffy jokes',
                upvotes: 9,
                comments: [{commento:'comment3'},
                    {commento:'comment4'}]
            }
    ];
  $scope.upVote = function(post){}
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <span>{{post.title}}</span>
    <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="upVote(post)" style="cursor:pointer;"></p> Upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    
    <p ng-repeat = "comment in post.comments">
        {{comment.commento}}
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax of ng-repeat is wrong:

```
<p ng-repeat comment in post.comments>
```

should be

```
<p ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
```

Answer (score 0):

ok was only an formatted error

```
<p ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
```

Comment: Please mark the answer that resolved the issue for you (tick mark) so that the question doesn't remain "unanswered". Unanswered questions sometimes make people spend time looking at the (already answered) question when they could be helping someone else.

Answer (score 0):

**Observations :**

- Use `<p ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">` instead of `<p ng-repeat comment in post.comments>`**.**
- `$scope.posts` object is not declared correctly. use `$scope.posts = []` instead of `$scope.posts: []`**.**

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.posts = [
        {
            title: 'Free pizza at club meetings',
            upvotes: 15,
            comments: [
                {commento:'comment1'},
                {commento:'comment2'}
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'End all club emails with Laffy Taffy jokes',
            upvotes: 9,
            comments: [],
        }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 comment" ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    <p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="upVote(post)" style="cursor:pointer;"></span> Upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
    </p>
    <p ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
    {{comment.commento}}
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```